# Delete the grey bar at the bottom of the UIView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

Why does all my UIViews have a grey bar at the bottom. I can hide it in runtime with the code self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;

But I need it hidden in development mode. I have tried changing the navigation controller properties to bottom bar = non, did nothing.

How can I get rid of this grey bar at the bottom in development mode?

[image: Grey Bottom Bar In Development Mode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your navigation controller and open the attributes inspector. Make sure the Bottom Bar property is set to None.

[image]

You can also do the same for individual viewControllers.

Comment: Individual property for the UIViews did it. Thanks.